# In a Keras Sequential model, Conv2D seems to require the kernel be narrower than the previous layer is thick. Why?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm creating a `Sequential` model in Keras that takes a colour image and convolves it through multiple `Conv2D` layers of approximately the same size and shape as the top layer (minus the edges sliced off by the convolutions, basically).

My understanding is as follows:

`kernel_size` indicates the patch size for each convolution's input
`filters` indicates the layer depth for each convolution's output.

I then do some other stuff after the convolutions, which isn't relevant here.

However, when I tried to compile my model prior to testing it on a little data, I discovered that Tensorflow complains when I try to make `kernel_size` for a given layer greater than `filters` for the previous layer. It doesn't actually say that; instead it says

> Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 1 for 'conv2d_2/convolution' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes [?,1,1022,1022], [3,3,1022,1]

which isn't exactly informative. However, I noticed that the numbers it puts in correspond to

> Negative dimension size caused by subtracting <this layer's `kernel_size`> from <previous layer's `filters`> ....

and setting `filters` to be higher stopped the error.

My question is: why should this be? I thought `filters` specified *depth*, and `kernel_size` specified *width*. There shouldn't be any need to fit a convolution patch into the thickness of the previous layer. Moreover, this problem *does not* occur on the first layer, whose channel depth (which I understand to be effectively equivalent to `filters`) is 3.

Is this a bug, or am I misinterpreting these parameters' meaning, or something else?

Code snippet:

```
__model = Sequential()

# feature layers
__model.add(Conv2D(input_shape=(3, iX, iY), data_format="channels_first", kernel_size=kernelfilters[0][0],
                   filters=kernelfilters[0][1], activation=ACTIVATION))

for kernelfilter in kernelfilters:
    __model.add(Conv2D(kernel_size=kernelfilter[0], filters=kernelfilter[1], activation=ACTIVATION))
```

The last line is the one that breaks.

Each `kernelfilter` in the `kernelfilters` array is a pair of numbers specifying a `kernel_size` and a `filters` value, in that order. `iX` and `iY` are the initial image dimensions. `ACTIVATION` is a constant, currently set to `"relu"` but I might change it later!

Comment: Please add a self-contained example that reproduces the error. To me it sounds like a confusion between channels_last and channels_first

Comment: No, it's not on the first layer but the middle layers. I'll grab the model code in a second.

Comment: channels_last and channelst_first refer to the image_data_format configurable parameter in Keras, it has nothing to do with first or last layers.

Comment: Ah, OK; wouldn't the middle layers nevertheless have a depth equal to `filters` and a width and height determined by the previous convolution, though? In other words, why would `channels_first` or `channels_last` affect that, since the dimensions are partly set automatically and partly through a named param?

Comment: Oh, and model code snippet is in! Thanks!

Comment: changing data_format changes how the data is interpreted, you have data_format="channels_first" in the first layer, why? If you don't know what it does, then do not change the default value.

Comment: I have that set so that the `input_shape` will be interpreted how I want (channels first, then image dimensions--as you see I've got `(3, iX, iY)`). According to the docs that's how it's used. What does it do to intermediate layers?

Comment: No, that is the wrong usage, for this to work you would have to change the data_format for each layer in the model.

Comment: Ah, got you. The Keras docs I saw didn't clarify that. Thanks! What *is* the default, though? I thought `channels_first` *was* the default. Obviously if I do this wrong, I will simply replace this error with it thinking I have a tiny, very multicoloured input ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your premise is wrong, this is not the case in general. This only happens if you fiddle with the `image_data_format` keras parameter (in `~/.keras/keras.kson`) or with the `data_format` parameter for each layer.

Changing this parameter in an in consistent way (in some layers only) would completely screw up how the data is interpreted, as it changes the position of the channels dimension, which could be interpreter as one of the spatial dimensions. for the TF backend (meaning the `input_shape` in the top layer should be a tuple of the form `(width, height, channels)`).

Comment: If set to the default, can I rely on Keras interpreting `input_shape` correctly with channels first? Alternatively, would setting `data_format` in intermediate layers correct this?

Comment: @AndrewWyld all shapes are by default channels_last if you use the TensorFlow backend. Its much easier to reshape your data so the channels dimension is at the end, than instead try to make Keras use channelst_first

Comment: Ahh, thanks. Strange that it doesn't propagate this through, but heigh ho!